# Marking when a SO is printed - Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I'm interested in hooking into the print report action on a Sales Order to mark the SO "Traveler Printed" when someone has printed that particular report.  Suggestions for how to accomplish this?  I know it's done on the PO but I'm struggling to parse out the where and how of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Customization Project Editor Code section, create a graph extension for SOOrderEntry.

Customization Project Editor has an Override Method feature that is handy for generating the event handler prototype:
[image]

You can then edit the generated stub definition like this:

```
namespace PX.Objects.SO
{ 
  public class SOOrderEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
    public delegate IEnumerable ReportDelegate(PXAdapter adapter, String reportID);

    [PXOverride]
    public IEnumerable Report(PXAdapter adapter, String reportID, ReportDelegate baseMethod)
    {
      if (reportID == "SO641010")
      {
          PXTrace.WriteInformation("I'm doing my things here, after report action has been invoked, just before report is actually launched.");
      }

      return baseMethod(adapter,reportID);
    }
    #endregion
  }
}
```